# Fill color diagonal dataframe python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, colors, fill

I would like to fill the cells in the diagonal of a pivot table dataframe(withe yellow for instance). I attached a picture with the code and the resulting table.

Thank you very much.[Resulting table + code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucJ4M.png)

Comment: Can you paste the code in the txt form here, images are not good to link.

Comment: Use styling. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html

Comment: @RockyLi I've already tried it, but it returns a panda io style object maybe im doing sth wrong, did this:

def color_diagonal(cell):
    color = 'yellow'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

m = matriz2016_2017_ejercicio.style.applymap(color_diagonal, 
                                         subset=[np.diag(matriz2016_2017_ejercicio)])

m

Comment: @pygo matriz2016_2017_ejercicio = comparacion_una_una.pivot_table(index=['Calificacion2016'], 
                          columns='Calificacion2017', aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)

there you go